# gdebi-gtk Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: segmentation-fault

```
$ gdebi-gtk
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is what I get. I've tried so many things with no success. I'm trying to open it, in order to download Parrot Security OS. I also downloaded Debian and got the same result. I also tried looking for the file, and it says the file can not be found. I also changed the core to unlimited which was on 0 when I first checked `ulimit -c`

Answer (score 0):

Probably this happens due to bugs in the gdebi package. There are several open bug reports about gdebi crashes: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdebi